# WSO2 APIM 4.2.0 - public SSL - Nosubject altenative DNS name matching localhost fount

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed APIM wsp2 4.2.0 with a domain xxx.xxx.x and then I installed the certificates wso2carbon.jks and client-truststore.jks but when I login to the consoles, admin, devportal and publisher I get error : error 500: the page canno be displayed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3oir.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdhhT.png)

I have temporarily solved the error by adding a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) that includes "localhost" to a self-signed ssl certificate, but that is not the ideal solution, because it must be with the public ssl certificate, but the public one cannot have a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) that includes "localhost".

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this issue?

Thanks

Caused
by:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching localhost found.
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert. createSSLException(Alert. java: 131)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl. TransportContext. fatal (TransportContext. java:376)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl. TransportContext. fatal (TransportContext. java:319) java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext. fatal (TransportContext. java:314)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl. CertificateMessage$12CertificateConsumer. checkServerCerts (CertificateMessage. java: 654)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer .onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer. consume (CertificateMessage. java: 369)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake. consume (SSHandshake. java: 392)

at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext. dispatch( HandshakeContext. java:478)
at java. base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpL$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction. run(SSLEngineImpl. java: 1082)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction. run(SSLEngineImpl. java: 1069)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask. run(SSLEngineImpl. java: 1016)
at java.base/java.util. ArrayList. forEach(ArrayList. java: 1541)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate. lambda$executeTasks$3(SSLFlowDelegate. java: 1073)
at java.net.http/jdk. internal.net.http.HttpClientImpL$DelegatingExecutor.execute(HttpClientImpl.java: 153)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate. executeTasks (SSLFlowDelegate. java: 1068)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.doHandshake(SSLFlowDelegate. java: 1034)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(SSFlowDelegate. iava:442)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(SSLFlowDelegate. java:264)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask. run(Sequentialscheduler. java: 175)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask. run(SequentialScheduler. java: 147)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common. SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask. run(SequentialScheduler. java: 198)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent. ThreadPooLExecutor. runworker (ThreadPoolExecutor. java: 1128) java.base/java.util.concurrent. ThreadPoolExecutor$worker. run(ThreadPoolExecutor. java:628)
1 more
by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching localhost found.
at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker. matchDNS (HostnameChecker. java:212)
at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker. match(HostnameChecker. java: 103)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.509TrustManagerImpl. checkIdentity (X509TrustManagerImpl. java:455)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.509TrustManager Impl. checkIdentity X509TrustManagerImpl. java: 415)
at java. base/sun.security.ss.509TrustManager Impl. checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl. java: 283)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.509TrustManagerImpl. checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl. java: 141)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$12CertificateConsumer. checkServerCerts (CertificateMessage. java: 632)
21 more

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: It should work without putting localhost under SAN. Can you share the entire error you get?

Comment: I have added the error shown in the logs in the description of the issue

Comment: Error 500: the page cannot be displayed
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Sale el mensaje de error en el portal admin, devportal, publisher, pero en el carbon si me deja ingresar n correctamente y valida el certificado.

Comment: 72:     HttpRequest getReq = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
73:             .uri(URI.create(settingsAPIUrl))
74:             .build();
75:     HttpResponse<String> settingsResult = client.send(getReq, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
76:
77:     Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
78:     Map settingsResponse = gson.fromJson(settingsResult.body(), Map.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I have entered, in the deployment.toml file the following line:
internal_hostname = "domain.com"

in the api-manager.sh

```
-Djdk.internal.httpclient.disableHostnameVerification=true
-Dorg.opensaml.httpclient.https.disableHostnameVerification=true \ \ \
-Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier=AllowAll \
```